# Can setState() of onChanged() in TextFormField be asynchronous?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

I've written some code to check if the username is already taken as it is being typed out.
I've used Cloud Firestore.

This is my TextFormField:

```
        TextFormField(
                      autovalidate: true,

                         validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                          ? 'Username cannot be empty.'
                          : ((!alphanumeric.hasMatch(val))
                              ? 'Username can have only a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _'
                              : null),

                        onChanged: (text) {
                        setState(() async {
                             doesUsernameExist =
                              await databaseService.checkIfUsernameExists(text);
                          username = text;

                        });
                        },
                      ),
```

When onChanged() is asynchronous, the validator does not work.
When onChanged() is not asynchronous and line with await is removed, the validator works perfectly.

How do I make both work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to mixing Async with non-Async in Flutter :P

The way I usually handle this is by dividing the async work into another method and calling that method between some sort of indicator like a loading icon or so:

```
onChanged: (text){
  // Show Loading Dialog
  _setUsername(text);
  // Navigator.pop() the loading dialog
}
```

where:

```
_setUsername(String name) async{
  bool valid = await databaseService.checkIfUsernameExists(name);
  if(valid){
    setState((){
      username = name;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! I definitely recommend you check out how to handle asynchronous programming in flutter since you'll need a lot of it :P